# Is it good practice to initialize an object while passing it to a method or should I initialize first then pass it?

Tags: java

I wasn't sure how to word this question for the title as I'm not sure if this practice has a name or not.

Is initializing an object and passing it through at the same time an acceptable practice, or should I always initialize on a separate line and pass it through on the next line? Are both examples fine?

Is this an acceptable space saving technique?

The static modifiers can be ignored as I just made a new project and left everything static as to create a quick example.

```
private static Rectangle2D rect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    exampleMethod1(rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 32, 32));

    // OR

    rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 32, 32)
    exampleMethod1(rect);
}

public static void exampleMethod1(Rectangle2D rect) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: it's the same things, but I prefer 1 shorter way

Comment: the second method seems better to me, I've never encountered the first one... The first one's issue is if you don't need to call exampleMethod1() anymore but yet still needs the rectangle, you might delete the line and thus the rect accidentally

Comment: Depends on your style. I always do it the shortest way possible, which would be the 1st one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most people consider #2 more readable, but this is going to be a personal preference generally.

Comment: i would agree, but i consider it very bad style to declare it a static field and not as a local variable in this case!

Comment: so you are saying that the question is primarily opinion-based

Comment: #2 is readable and debuggable.

Comment: You can ignore the static modifiers as I just set this up in a new project and left everything static just to create an example.

Answer (score 0):

I must agree with Louis Wasserman on this and the reason why #2 is more readable is simply because there are two operations in two separate lines. If you are to apply the same approach and put everything in the same line then it could get nasty a bit, thing of this silly example:

```
exampleMethod1(rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(isValid ? 0 : 1, 0, 
                 someNumber + 2, getValue()));
```